# Strange error in Laravel Eloquent query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I know it is a known issue, there are other questions on SO regarding this issue, but none of them was useful. The raw query works fine if I directly run against the database when it run throw Laravel it gives an error.
What's the hell wrong going on?

Query:

```
Order::selectRaw("COUNT(id) AS `data`, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%Y') AS new_date, YEAR(created_at) AS `year`, MONTH(created_at) AS `month`")
        ->groupBy('year')->get();
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'orders.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select COUNT(id) AS `data`, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%Y') AS new_date, YEAR(created_at) AS `year`, MONTH(created_at) AS `month` from `orders` group by `year`)
```

Comment: Can you give us around idea what are you trying to achieve? Coding in Laravel for a long time, never ran into situation so I do have to create raw sql queries, 100% of time Model and Eloquent, worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is database error and not related to Laravel. Running exactly same query in database should fail also, if it is not failing then it should :).

You need to group by other fields in your query also, "new_date", "month" and "year". Try something like this:

```
Order::selectRaw("COUNT(id) AS `data`, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%Y') AS new_date, YEAR(created_at) AS `year`, MONTH(created_at) AS `month`")
    ->groupBy('year', 'month', 'new_date')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any problem when you run this at your database then it's the laravel setting in your file **config->database.php**, just set the `'strict'` to `'false'`.

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```